# How to make ng-click works only on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angular and trying to toggle a class on click only on current link.
But on click it is working on all links. I want it works only on current element. 
For which we use (this) in jquery.

script:

```
var data = '<td  id="'+index+'" class="drag drop"><div class="ui-resizable tac"><div class="ui-resizable">' + header[index].description + '<br>' + header[index].name +'</div></div><div id="div'+index+'"  class="report-container" style="display:inline-block;float:left;"><ul class="report-list">';
            for( var key = 0; key < listTemp.length; key ++){
                data+= "<li  class='bg-l-grey' ng-class='{ opened:  selectedIndex == 0}' style='background:" + listTemp[key].color +"'><span><em class='left'>" + listTemp[key].mpValue + "</em><em class='right'>" + parseInt(listTemp[key].yield) + "</em></span>"+
                        '<div class="list-swiper bg-black" ng-click="selectedIndex = 0"><span class="swipe-left"></span><span class="swipe-right"></span></div><div class="report-icon-list bg-l-green"><a href="#" class="cht-doc"><span><i class="cht-sprite"></i></span></a><a href="#" class="cht-cam"><span><i class="cht-sprite"></i></span></a><a href="#" class="cht-add"><span><i class="cht-sprite"></i></span></a></div></li>';
            }
            data+= '</ul></div></td>';

$scope.openSwap = function($event) {
        // body...
        var elementParent = $event.currentTarget.parentElement.offsetParent;
        angular.element(elementParent).toggleClass("opened");
        if ($(elementParent).hasClass("opened")) {

        }else {
            console.log(false);
        }
        $event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

I want click event on ".list-swiper" class and class toggle on parent li.

Comment: you should not build your DOM in here if you use angular. Can you create a small plunker/jsfiddle of your work?

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle a class and use `ng-class` with this:

```
<div class="list-swiper bg-black" 
     ng-class="{ opened: thisElementClicked }" 
     ng-click="thisElementClicked = true">..</div>
```

This will add a class 'opened' to the `div` element when you click it.

You can of course also add the `ng-class` to the parent, which will add the class on the parent:

```
<li ng-class="{ opened: thisElementClicked }">
    <div class="list-swiper bg-black" 
         ng-click="thisElementClicked = true">..</div>
</li>
```

You probably have multiple `li` elements, where you might want to do this more dynamically:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{ opened: selectedIndex == 0 }">
        <div class="list-swiper bg-black" 
             ng-click="openSwap(0)">..</div>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ opened: selectedIndex == 1 }">
        <div class="list-swiper bg-black" 
             ng-click="openSwap(1)">..</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

controller:

```
$scope.openSwap = function (index) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    // .. more
}
```

---

Even simpler, if you can build the `li`'s dynamically:

```
$scope.swipers = [
    { title: "first swiper"},
    { title: "second swiper"},
    // ..
}

$scope.openSwap = function (index) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    // or toggle, depends what you want:
    // if ($scope.selectedIndex == index) {
    //     $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
    // } else {
    //     $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    // }
}
```

view:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="swiper in swipers"
        ng-class="{ opened: selectedIndex == $index }">
        <div class="list-swiper bg-black" 
             ng-click="openSwap($index)">{{ swiper.title }}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want click event on ".list-swiper" class and class toggle on parent li.

Comment: ^^thanks for help. Used ur provided code but it didn't help. Class is not toggling on click

Comment: You added some code and I see why that wouldn't work. You hardcode the index as 0 in there, instead use your `for`-loop `key` variable as index. Or probably you should rewrite that whole stuff

Answer (score 0):

"jqLite" (defined on the angular.element page) provides DOM traversal methods like `children()`, `parent()`, `contents()`, `find()`, `next()` **(but not previous())**. There is no selector-like method.

You can try core JavaScript's querySelector, follow link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector.

There is no any $(this) concept in angular what you do in jquery, instead you have to traverse till the element through javascripts querySelector or angular.element(document).find(...) or $document.find()

for documentation find the checkout below link:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score -2):

Use `ng-class` to change the class on this particular link.

```
<ANY class="ng-class: expression;"> ... </ANY>
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: This place is to help people, not to criticise other people trying to help.

Comment: It was an helpfull comment for you to avoid downvotes.